# Writing to memory beginning by null bytes

Tags: c, security, format-string

Assuming this code :

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    int main(int argc, char** argv){
    char fonction[50] = "/usr/bin/passwd ";
    char messageAccueil[100] = "changement du mot de passe de  : ";
    if(argc == 1){
        printf("vous devez passer un username en parametre \n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf(messageAccueil);
    printf(argv[1]); //<-- format string vulnerability here !!
    if(strcmp(argv[1], "root")==0){
        printf("vous ne pensiez quand meme pas pouvoir changer le mot de passe de root si facilement ?\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("\n");
    strncat(fonction,argv[1],38);
    system(fonction);
    return 0;
}
```

I want to exec shell by exploiting format string vulnerability,
So, I wanted to rewrite `strcmp` function address from GOT by the address of my shellcode stored into environment variable.

`gdb` gave me :

```
(gdb) info functions
0x0000000000400570  strcmp@plt
(gdb) disas 0x400570
Dump of assembler code for function strcmp@plt:
0x0000000000400570 <+0>:    jmp    QWORD PTR [rip+0x20070a]#0x600c80 <strcmp@got.plt>
0x0000000000400576 <+6>:    push   0x6
0x000000000040057b <+11>:   jmp    0x400500
End of assembler dump.
```

So I want to write my shellcode address to `0x00600c80`

How can i pass nullbyte to my `./changepasswd` file ?

I'm actually trying this exploit :

```
/changepasswd $(echo -e '\x80\x0c\x60\x00____\x84\x0c\x60\x00')%65527d%136\$x%59017d%137\$x
```

This give me the adress **`600c845f`**

But the `\x00` as no influence and is not stored into the stack.

I found that the fact adress start by 00 could by and ascii armouring issue but exec-shield option is totally absent from my system.

So I'm looking for a way **to write the 00 into my stack** OR to **get my GOT addresses to be started by something else than 00..**.

Comment: Of course there's the one close vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two questions here. Or, better said, two impossibilities.

First, there is a shell question: how to pass a string containing a NUL as a command-line argument to a utility.

Shell variables cannot contain `NUL`s, so there is no way to construct the parameter string and pass it as an argument. [Note 1] However, you can construct a stream containing a `NUL` and pipe that into the `stdin` of some utility. It only remains to find a utility which converts its input into a command-line argument for some other utility; that would be `xargs`. So you might try the following:

```
printf '\0This is an argument' | xargs -I{} ./victim {}
```

However, that won't work (and most implementations of `xargs` won't even let you try it [Note 2]), because of the second issue: the `argv` parameter to `main` is an array of *`NUL`-terminated* strings, so each command-line argument is terminated by the first `NUL`. Consequently, even if you managed to find a way to pass all the bytes into the `argv` array, the utility would treat the `NUL` as terminating the argument, not as part of the argument. (For example, `printf(argv[1])` will print the bytes from the first argument until it reaches a `NUL`; the `NUL` signals the end of the format string.)

But you won't find a way to do that, because the `exec*` system library functions (one of which is necessary to pass arguments into a another executable) will also treat the `NUL` as terminating the respective argument. Since the `exec*` function needs to *copy* the arguments into the address space of the new executable image, and the copy will terminate when the end of the argument is reached, any bytes following the `NUL` will be left uncopied.

---

#### Notes:

1. Shells have different ways to deal with attempts to insert `NUL`s using command substitution. Bash, for example, just deletes the `NUL`s, but other shells might terminate the substitution at the first `NUL`.
2. For the record, the Gnu implementation of `xargs` will produce the following useful message:

   > xargs: Warning: a NUL character occurred in the input.  It cannot be passed through in the argument list.  Did you mean to use the --null option?

Comment: so why my \x00 character doesn't end my argument ? by passing `$(echo -e '\x80\x0c\x60\x00____\x84\x0c\x60\x00')%65527d%136\$x%59017d%137\$x` all the string is passed as argument but only the \x00 are ignored and not stored in stack

Comment: @gfrancqu: because bash removes NUL characters when it performs the `$(...)` substitution. Not all shells act that way; some would terminate the argument at the first NUL.  I could have mentioned that, I suppose.

Comment: would this still be a problem with python, perl or with any other language ?

Comment: @gfrancqu: The only way to execute an executable is with `exec*`. Please read my answer again, and then do some reading of manpages. (If you want to write exploits, you'll need to do some research :) )